# How to search a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."users" (
    "roles" _text CHECK ((array_ndims(roles) = 2) AND (array_length(roles, 2) = 3)),
);
```

So I end up with a column value like:

```
{{user,owner,123},{organization,owner,456}}
```

How can I search this column for the 3rd value in each nested array, like `SELECT * from users where roles[1][3] = '456'` (which should return this `user`)?

Comment: This level of de-normalization will bite you more often than you can imagine right now. I would strongly recommend to go for a properly normalized model. If you really think you need to de-normalize with nested structures, then you might want to consider using a JSON column instead where it is probably easier to to validate and access individual elements

Comment: @bihireboris I did exactly what the comment above suggests and normalized my model. I created another table with only the `roles`, and mapped a User ID to the table in my original post

Answer (score 0):

If you have this data and want to find the `id` whose second value in the multi dimension array is 0:

| id | roles |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {{3,1},{5,1},{2,0},{4,0}} |
| 2 | {{10,1},{11,1}} |

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY_AGG(item) item
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        roles,
        UNNEST(roles [:] [0:1]) item,
        UNNEST(roles [:] [2:2]) val
    FROM
        users) AS unnested_arr
WHERE
    val = 0
GROUP BY
    id;
```